# Python : Find a node in JSON if not then enter the node

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am currently having a trouble in solving this problem using python 2.7. Basically I need to check if a child node exist inside a parent node. If yes then just print the key and values and if not then insert the child node with key and value.

The json structure looks like:

```
{
"Movies": {
    "Drama": {
        "main": {
            "actor": "MR x",
            "actress": "Miss Y"
        }
    },
    "Action": {
        "Aux": {
            "director": "MR J",
            "Producer": "Mr K"
        },
        "main": {
            "actor": "MR yyyy",
            "actress": "Mrs XXXX"
        }
    }
  },

  "Serial":{-------
    ...................
   }
}
```

In above json structure, I need to first check if the Subnode "Aux" exist or not, if not then I need to add the whole block,

```
        "Aux": {
            "director": "MR J",
            "Producer": "Mr K"
        },
```

inside the "Action" node. 
How can I do it, so far I have done this,

```
try:
    json_file = ('record.json')
    with open(json_file,'r+') as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)
        for item in parent:

except Exception, e:
    print e
```

How can I solve this Problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only want to check for subnodes in `Movies`, right?

Comment: Well, to be detailed, there are more nodes like "serial", "documentary"etc , Movies is one of them. *** I have edited in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split your problem into two steps. Reading and writing.
In the first step you can check if `Aux``is in the keys already. If not you add it.
Then you simply open the file to write and write the cleaned data to it:

```
import json

with open("record.json", "r") as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
    for genre in data:
        for movie_genre in data[genre]:
            if "Aux" not in data[genre][movie_genre].keys():
                data[genre][movie_genre]["Aux"] = {"director": "MR J", "Producer": "Mr K"}

with open("record.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much your approach is the best and has solved my problem

Comment: There is one small glitch, If the node "AUX" is found then, I tried to print, but somehow the response is printed more than 20 times. Why is it so ? and How can I get rid of it

Comment: with open("record.json", "r") as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
    for genre in data:
        for movie_genre in data[genre]:
            if "Aux" not in data[genre][movie_genre].keys():
                print '\n----- There is no AUX hence adding the new node'
                data[genre][movie_genre]["Aux"] = {"director": "MR J", "Producer": "Mr K"}
                with open("record.json", "w") as outfile:
                outfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
            else:
                 print '\n No need to add the AUX'

Comment: @ k-nut : here is the link http://pastebin.com/NcxuA2tG    , The last print line will be printer more than 20 times if there is the subnode.

Comment: Yes, because this is printed for every node that does not need the addition. You should also move out the writing to file like this: http://pastebin.com/nxZre5FN

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether Aux is available in JSON dictionary, if not, you can add it:

```
try:
    json_file = ('record.json')
    with open(json_file,'r+') as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)
        if 'Aux' not in data:
          data['Movies']['Action']['Aux'] = {"director": "MR J", "Producer": "Mr K"}

except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Comment: But I did answer to the question. The hard code part always can be parameterized or variablized.